# Overlap ranges in array

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a program in ruby 1.9.3 ver. which collects unique value ranges and then calculates amount of numbers in these ranges. 
For example lets use 3 ranges (1..3), (6..8) and (2..4). It will return array with two ranges (1..4), (6..8) and amount of numbers - 7.
I wrote the following code:

```
z= []
def value_ranges(start, finish, z)
  range = (start..finish)
  arr = z
  point = nil
  if arr.empty?
    point = nil
  else
    arr.each { |uniq|
      if overlap?(uniq,range) == true
        point = arr.index(uniq)
        break
      else
        point = nil
      end
    }
  end
  if point != nil
    if arr[point].first >= start && arr[point].end <= finish
      range = (start..finish)
    elsif arr[point].first >= start
      range = (start..arr[point].end)
    elsif arr[point].end <= finish
      range = (arr[point].first..finish)
    else
      range = (arr[point].first..arr[point].end)
    end
    arr[point] = range
  else
    arr << range
  end
  print arr
end

def overlap?(x,y)
  (x.first - y.end) * (y.first - x.end) >= 0
end
```

Problem comes when program meets a range which overlaps two already collected ranges. 
For example (1..5) (7..9) (11..19) and the next given range is (8..11). 
It should link both ranges and return the following result - (1..5),(7..19). 
I don't have an idea how to recheck whole array without creating infinite loop. Also what is the best way to calculate amount of numbers in ranges?

Comment: how about `.to_a.size` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two Ruby-like ways of doing it.

```
arr = [1..3, 6..8, 2..4]
```

**#1 Efficient approach**

First calculate the amalgamated ranges:

```
a = arr[1..-1].sort_by(&:first).each_with_object([arr.first]) do |r,ar|
  if r.first <= ar.last.last
    ar[-1] = ar.last.first..[ar.last.last,r.last].max
  else
    ar << r
  end
end
  #=> [1..4, 6..8]
```

Then compute the total number of elements in those ranges:

```
a.reduce(0) { |tot,r| tot + r.size }
  #=> [1..4, 6..8].reduce(0) { |tot,r| tot + r.size }
  #=> 7
```

*Explanation*

```
b = arr[1..-1]
  #=> [6..8, 2..4]
c = b.sort_by(&:first)      
  #=> [2..4, 6..8]
enum = c.each_with_object([1..3])
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2..4, 6..8]:each_with_object([1..3])>
```

The contents of the enumerator `enum` will be passed into the block and assigned to the block variables by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each), which will call [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each). We can see the contents of the enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[2..4, [1..3]], [6..8, [1..3]]]
```

and we can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to step through the enumerator. The first element of the enumerator passed to the block by `each` is `[2..4, [1..3]]`. This is assigned to the block variables as follows:

```
r, ar = enum.next
   #=> [2..4, [1..3]] 
r  #=> 2..4 
ar #=> [1..3]
```

We now perform the block calculation

```
  if r.first <= ar.last.last
    #=> 2 <= (1..3).last
    #=> 2 <= 3
    #=> true
    ar[-1] = ar.last.first..[ar.last.last,r.last].max
      #=> ar[-1] = 1..[3,4].max
      #=> ar[-1] = 1..4
      #=> 1..4
  else # not executed this time
    ar << r
  end
```

This is not so mysterious. So I don't have to keep saying "the last range of `ar`", let me define:

```
ar_last = ar.last
  #=> 1..3
```

First of all, because we began by sorting the ranges by the beginning of each range, we know that when each element of `enum` is passed into the block:

```
ar_last.first <= r.first
```

For each element of `enum` passed into the block for which:

```
r.first <= ar_last.last
```

we compare `r.last` with `ar_last.last`. There are two possibilities to consider:

- `r.last <= ar_last.last`, in which case the two ranges overlap and therefore `ar_last` would not change; and
- `r.last > ar_last.last`, in which case the upper end of `ar_last` must be increased to `r.last`.

Here,

```
2 = r.first <= ar_last.last = 3
4 = r.last  >  ar_last.last = 3
```

so `ar_last` is changed from `1..3` to `1..4`.

`each` now passes the last element of `enum` into the block:

```
r, ar = enum.next
   #=> [6..8, [1..4]] 
r  #=> 6..8 
ar #=> [1..4] 

if r.first <= ar.last.last
  #=> (6 <= 4) => false this time
  ...
else # executed this time
  ar << r
    #=> ar << (6..8)
    #=> [1..4, 6..8] 
end
```

and

```
a = ar #=> [1..4, 6..8]
```

This time, `r.first > ar_last.last`, meaning the range `r` does not overlap `ar_last`, so we append `r` to `ar`, and `ar_last` now equals `r`.

Lastly:

```
a.reduce(0) { |tot,r| tot + r.size }
  #=> [1..4, 6..8].reduce(0) { |tot,r| tot + r.size }  
  #=> 7
```

which we could alternatively write:

```
a.map(&:size).reduce(:+)
```

**#2 Easy but inefficient**

Here is an easy, but not especially efficient, method that uses [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), newly-minted in v2.2.

```
arr = [(1..3), (6..8), (2..4)]
```

To calculate the amagamated ranges:

```
a = arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
       .uniq
       .sort
       .slice_when { |i,j| i+1 != j }
       .map { |ar| (ar.first..ar.last) }
  #=> [1..4, 6..8]
```

The total number of elements in those ranges is calculated as in #1

*Explanation*

Here are the steps:

```
b = arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4]
c = b.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4]
d = c.sort
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
e = d.slice_when { |i,j| i+1 != j }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f81629584f0>:each> 
a = e.map { |ar| (ar.first..ar.last) }
  #=> [1..4, 6..8]
```

We can see the contents of the enumerator `e` by converting it to an array:

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```